# CrossRef Rest API with Zenodo DOI

Tags: doi, zenodo

Is it possible to get the metadata of a publication in Zenodo using the CrossRef Rest API?

For instance, calling `https://api.crossref.org/works/10.5281/zenodo.2594632` returns `SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The basic answer is no. This is because Zenodo uses DataCite, not Crossref, as its DOI registration agency. You can identify the registration agency for a DOI by sending a request to `https://doi.org/ra/{doi}`, then, based on whether the agency is Crossref or DataCite, you can request metadata directly from their API. So, your request would be `https://api.datacite.org/dois/10.5281/zenodo.2594632`.

Normally, you can also get back standard metadata for a DOI without knowing the registration agency through the Crosscite content negotiation service (see https://citation.crosscite.org/docs.html ). However, at the current moment I am receiving a "503 Service Temporarily Unavailable" response to content negotiation requests for DataCite DOIs...